# Testing javascipt using jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I am trying to do testing in jasmine. I am very new to it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
//result is an array of data.
var availableTags = new Array();
    function show(result) {
        var items = new Array();
        var stuff = result.answer;  
        $.each(result, function(i, result) {
                items.push(stuff);
        });

        return items;
    }

describe("check is data exists", function(){
       it("check data", function(){
           expect(show("a")).toEqual("a");
      });      

   });
```

Comment: What is your question?  What error are you getting?  What isn't working?  Please provide more detail because we have very little to go on in order to help you the way your question is currently written.

Comment: If you are new to jasmine and would like to have any suggestions on references , it would be good to post the same directly. Your question doesn't seems to be proper. Having a clear info would help for the people to answer you ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope your questions is not about any problem, Here i'm attaching basic things for you to understand jasmine . I guess you have already did the setup of jasmine to start writing test cases. Here is a sample example.

```
function helloWorld() {
 return 'Hello world!';
}

describe('Hello world', function () {
 it('says hello', function () {
   expect(helloWorld()).toEqual('Hello world!');
 });

 it('Is defined', function () {
   var name = "Alex";
   expect(name).toBeDefined(); // Return true as name is defined. 
 });
});
```

Here is the [Reference](http://evanhahn.com/how-do-i-jasmine/) to understand the basics. Happy coding.

Comment: What if it does not return anything. For example, if that function only has string on it used, but will not return anything.

Comment: @user3557656 : If your function does not return anything then the test case will fail and you would be knowing the cause to fix it.

Comment: Thank you. But what if is an array like {"a", "b", "c"}. how do i check if a exist in that array.

Comment: {} isn't an array.  That's an object.

Comment: @user3557656  If you wanted to check whether an object contains a property you can use `expect(array).toContain('a')`.